# What's the difference between my downvoted question and this upvoted question

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I asked a question about would it be better to move to California to find a California job because I live in South Korea. I'm originally from California.

[Working in South Korea. I want to relocate back to California](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/66985/working-in-south-korea-i-want-to-relocate-back-to-california)

This other question is about should he move to California to find a job in California

[Do I have to live in a specific location to find a job there?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/71791/do-i-have-to-live-in-california-to-find-a-job-there)

What is the difference between my question and the other question? Why was mine closed?  I want to know so I can work on rewording my question so they don't get closed in the future.

Comment: "Why was mine closed?" - Your question was "closed as off-topic". The other question already has 4 close votes, so most likely there won't be any difference between the two fairly soon.

Comment: I cast the final close vote.  The new question could have been closed for any number of reasons for being off topic.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Ah okay. I guess the fact that I saw an upvote and no close made me feel like people thought that questions was okay.

Comment: @bmarkham up and down votes have nothing to do with Close votes. They are 2 separate Systems. something with 1000 upvotes can be closed.

Comment: I dont know if it would help but you might want to restate your question as looking for suggestions on how to get a job in California while living abroad rather than a should I/shouldn't I.

Comment: @bmarkham - both are closed now. So basically there is no real difference.

Answer (score 1):

Voting is very individual.  There are guidelines on how SE would like you to base your votes, but they are not rules that must be followed.  In the end with the exception of [serial downvoting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me), your votes are your votes and the way you vote is your decision.

I would guess that the other question was better received because it was more broadly applicable.  Your question is pretty focused on your situation where the other question is applicable to the 7+ billion people who do not live in California.  In addition really the answers to the question can likely apply to anywhere in the US.  That said neither question is particularly well received in that both questions are under 10 votes.